# Way to stop column/table change on sails lift

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm using the sails version 0.11.2. Below is the code for

> config/models.js

in my sails app

```
/**
 * Default model configuration
 * (sails.config.models)
 *
 * Unless you override them, the following properties will be included
 * in each of your models.
 *
 * For more info on Sails models, see:
 * http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM
 */

module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'mysqldb',
  migrate: 'safe',
  schema : true
};
```

As per the sails [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings), migrate: 'safe' should stop auto migrations and not change any columns or tables in the database.

But still every time a comment an attribute any of the model and try lifting the sails app, the column associated to the attribute gets deleted from mysql database.

Note: Please comment if you need any additional information or sample code, in case of queries.

Comment: Can you show us all the code of config/models.js? Which version of sails are you using?

Comment: @piscator I've updated the question with complete file for config/models.js and also the sails version.

Comment: try to move the schema option to each model you use, schema: true,

  connection: 'mysqldb',
  tableName: 'yourTable',
  attributes: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code `migrate: 'safe'` in every model individually has resolved this issue. Now the model for a Consumer which is in file consumer.js looks as below:

```
/**
* Consumer.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {
  migrate      : 'safe',
  autoPK       : true,
  autoCreatedAt: true,
  autoUpdatedAt: true,
  attributes   : {
    name: {
      type     : 'string',
      required : true,
      minLength: 3
    },

    email: {
      type    : 'string',
      required: true,
      unique  : true
    },
  tableName    : 'consumers'
};
```

Although solution works but I believe a better solution that does not involve this code reputation in all models is still out there. So not marking this question as resolved with this answer.